# What is a SMSMigrator log on MacOS?

Tags: macos, sqlite, macos-mojave

What is SMSMigrator? 
Is there a database of my SMS on my MacBook?
Is this a normal log?
What is it doing with deleted messages and why all the SQL stuff?

[image: Log1]

[image: Log2]

[image: Log3]